# How to implement soft-argmax in caffe?

Tags: caffe

In Caffe deep-learning framework there is an argmax layer which is not differentiable and hence can not be used for end to end training of a CNN.
Can anyone tell me how I could implement the soft version of argmax which is soft-argmax?

I want to regress coordinates from heatmap and then use those coordinates in loss calculations. I am very new to this framework therefore no idea how to do this. any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what you want, but there are following options:

1. Use L2 loss to train regression task (EuclideanLoss). Or SmoothL1Loss (from SSD Caffe by Wei Lui), or L1 (don't know were you get it).
2. Use softmax with cross-entropy loss (SoftmaxWithLoss) to train classification task with classes corresponding to the possible values of x or y coordinate.  For example, one loss layer for x, and one for y.  SoftmaxWithLoss accepts label as a numeric value, and casts it to int with static_cast().  But take into account that implementation doesn't check that the casted value is within 0..(num_classes-1) range, so you have to be careful.
3. If you want something more unusual, you'll have to write you own layer in C++, C++/CUDA or Python+NumPy.  This is very often the case unless you are already using someone other's implementation.